# Trying to embed a video when a link is clicked in jQuery

Tags: jquery, youtube, embed

I'm trying to embed a video onclick rather than all 10 at once to increase load time. What would be the best way of doing this?. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<script type="text/Javascript">
    $('#rssdata').ready(function()
    {
        var pipe_url = 'http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=4ac421def2dc13ca08c0eef36386563d&_render=json';
enter code here



var i = 1;

$.getJSON(pipe_url,function(data)
{

$(data.value.items).each(function(index,item)
{

var embed_link = item.link.replace("https://youtube.com/watch?v=",              "https://www.youtube.com/embed/");

var youtube_Embed = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="'+ embed_link + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'


var item_html = '<li><div data-toggle="collapse" href="#element' + i + '"><a href="'+item.link+'">'+item.title+'<\/a></div><\/li>';

item_html += '<div class="collapse" id="element' + i + '">' + youtube_Embed + '</div>';

$('#rssdata ul.rss-items').append(item_html);

i++;
});
$('#rssdata div.loading').fadeOut();
$('#rssdata ul.rss-items').slideDown();
});
});
</script>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="video"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/zsYjsgm4Psg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>

<ul class="list_video">
 <li><a href="javascript:load_video('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWHfY_lvKIQ')">Learning from StackOverflow.com</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:load_video('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZWBtfSBlp8')">Joel Spolsky - StackOverflow.com </a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:load_video('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4ZPBPUA30M')">Jeff Atwood - Stackoverflow.com</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:load_video('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWHfY_lvKIQ')">Learning from StackOverflow.com</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:load_video('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZWBtfSBlp8')">Joel Spolsky - StackOverflow.com </a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:load_video('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4ZPBPUA30M')">Jeff Atwood - Stackoverflow.com</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:load_video('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWHfY_lvKIQ')">Learning from StackOverflow.com</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:load_video('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZWBtfSBlp8')">Joel Spolsky - StackOverflow.com </a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:load_video('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4ZPBPUA30M')">Jeff Atwood - Stackoverflow.com</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:load_video('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWHfY_lvKIQ')">Learning from StackOverflow.com</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:load_video('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZWBtfSBlp8')">Joel Spolsky - StackOverflow.com </a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:load_video('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4ZPBPUA30M')">Jeff Atwood - Stackoverflow.com</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:load_video('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWHfY_lvKIQ')">Learning from StackOverflow.com</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:load_video('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZWBtfSBlp8')">Joel Spolsky - StackOverflow.com </a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:load_video('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4ZPBPUA30M')">Jeff Atwood - Stackoverflow.com</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.container{
    width:800px;
    border:2px solid #333;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-family:arial;
    background-color:#000;
}
.video{float:left;}
ul.list_video{float:left;list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;width:240px;overflow-y:scroll;height:315px;}
ul.list_video li{font-size:10pt;}
ul.list_video li a{
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#09C;
    padding:3px;
    text-align:left;
    background-color:#333;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
ul.list_video li a:hover{background-color:#000;}
```

## Javascript + jQuery

```
function load_video(link){
    link = link.replace("https:","");
    link = link.replace("watch?v=","embed/");
    $('.video').html('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="'+link+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>')
}
```

I allowed myself to make a list of video and click to change the iframe URL parsing a video from YouTube

Here : http://jsfiddle.net/XdZm5/2/

Comment: how would i include my json feed into this?